# Why is it easier to turn a heavy hanging object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

Assume if we had a 2 tonne weight placed on ground attached with a rope that we can use to turn the object around. It will immensely hard to turn that object around by pulling the rope. However, if the weight was lifted to a certain height by a crane, when we try to turn that weight around; the force and the work is very low compared to the force needed to move the same object when it is on the floor.

Why is this?

Does the earth gravitational pull affect the amount of force required to turn the object?

Comment: Do You mean the lack of ground friction when the object is lifted?

Comment: @Wojciech You could say that. I don't see how the friction can make a real difference on the force needed to turn. I understand it contributes to the turning force to a certain extent. But, it doesn't contribute to all of the force.

Comment: Around which axis would You like to turn the object?

Comment: Assuming the weight is cylindrical, I would say somewhere in the middle of the side of the cylinder.

Comment: So the block will move in relation to the ground and the friction forces will act against. That is  the only reason.

Comment: So... You are telling me that if I had a huge weight on one of the smoothest surface in the planet. The amount of force is will much lower than the turning it when it is on Air! :/

Comment: Did I say that? Why do You think so?

Answer (score 3):

It is the elimination of friction on the ground.  The friction on the air is very small, as is the resistance of the rope to twisting.  No matter how smooth the floor, the friction will be much higher than the resistance of the hanging weight.  This is why air bearings were invented.